# Return an Object of Counts on GraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am trying to create a GraphQL query that collects multiple counts on a React project, but i can't figure out the exact type that I should enter.

The Code :

```
    import {   GraphQLInt,   GraphQLNonNull } from 'graphql' import * as moment from 'moment' import orm from '../../orm' import authDecorator from '../helpers/auth-decorator'

interface IQueryMissionCountArgs {   authToken: string }

export default authDecorator({   requireAdmin: true,   requireAuth: true })({   type: Object(new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)),   async resolve (
      args: IQueryMissionCountArgs   ) {
    const lastWeekAcceptedMissionsCount = await orm.models.Mission.count({
      where: {
        createdAt: {
          $between: [moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate(), new Date()]
        },
        status: 'accepted'
      }
    })
    const lastWeekPostedMissionsCount = await orm.models.Mission.count({
      where: {
        createdAt: {
          $between: [moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate(), new Date()]
        }
      }
    })
    return {
      lastWeekPostedMissions: lastWeekPostedMissionsCount,
      lastWeekAcceptedMissions: lastWeekAcceptedMissionsCount,
    }   } })
```

This is returning this error :

> Int cannot represent non 32-bit signed integer value: [object Object]\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you've defined for the field is an integer:

```
type: Object(new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt))
```

but you're returning an Object with two properties (`lastWeekPostedMissions` and `lastWeekAcceptedMissions`).

You need to define a new GraphQLObjectType, something like this:

const WeeklyMissionSummary = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'WeeklyMissionSummary',
  fields: {
    lastWeekPostedMissions: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
    lastWeekAcceptedMissions: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
  },
})

Then you can use that as the type for your field:

```
type: new GraphQLNonNull(WeeklyMissionSummary)
```

Comment: I'm almost there, it simply returns "GraphQLError: Field "allMissionStatistics" of type "WeeklyMissionSummary!" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "allMissionStatistics" now

Comment: you need to modify your request to actually include those two fields

Comment: I don't get what you mean ?

Comment: In the request you send to the server, when you request the `allMissionStatistics` field, you can't just request the field itself, because it's now an object, so you have to specify which fields on the object to return, like this: `allMissionStatistics { lastWeekPostedMissions lastWeekAcceptedMissions }`

Comment: Thank you, the answer is accepted as the correct one, I'm just having an issue now with the fact that  all queries are returning null while when running each alone it returns correct values